# how to get value of option from dynamically generated selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using following script for generating select

```
var opts = $.parseJSON(response);
$.each(opts, function(i, d) {
    if (i == 0) {
        $('#movie').append('<option value="' + d.movie_id + '" onclick="selectMovie(this.value)"selected>' + d.movie_name + '</option>');
    } else {
        $('#movie').append('<option value="' + d.movie_id + '" onclick="selectMovie(this.value)">' + d.movie_name + '</option>');
    }

});
```

but can't get the default value using

```
$('#movie').val()
```

or

```
var tmp = document.getElementById('movie').value;
```

need help

Comment: You need to get the value after appending option

Comment: yes i need after appending

Comment: What he means is you can only attempt to get that value after the append operations have completed. Since your call is asynchronous, you either have to do it in your callback, or you'll need to use a promise so that you don't attempt to do it until the ajax call has been resolved.

Comment: how i can do that kinakuta

Comment: You can use promises as @kinakuta suggested, or you can use a blocking way of iterating over the elements of the object (e.g. `for` loop)

Comment: Include the code making the ajax call and I can show both methods I suggested.

Comment: Also, do avoid binding events with inline JS. jQuery can handle the click event on the `<option>` elements easily.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving the data asynchronously that's why the element isn't in the DOM yet when you try to access it.

You have 2 options:

a) Use the `aync: false` as an option insde your $.ajax function will allow you to make a synchronous request. The JS after it will be executed when the ajax call is finished.

b) The better way is to use the `success` callback of the ajax function. When the response has been received by the client you can loop through it using your codesnippet above.

Simply put `$('#movie').val()` behind your each loop inside the success callback.

If it's still not working you have to tell jQuery to wait with the execution until the .each loop is done. Sometimes elements created by this can't be accessed by just putting the function call after the each loop.

In this case you can use `.promise()` like so:

```
$.each(opts, function(i, d) {
  if (i == 0) {
    $('#movie').append('<option value="' + d.movie_id + '"      onclick="selectMovie(this.value)"selected>' + d.movie_name + '</option>');
  } else {
    $('#movie').append('<option value="' + d.movie_id + '" onclick="selectMovie(this.value)">' + d.movie_name + '</option>');
  }
}).promise().done(function(){ $('#movie').val() });
```

Comment: IMHO, `async: false` is generally a bad idea. It will hold up script execution and freeze the browser until a reply is returned from the remote server.

Comment: I know, thats why I said it's an option but the other one is better :P